# How to tell the difference between two BLE Characteristics with the same UUID swift iOS

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth-lowenergy

I have two BLE peripherals and want to monitor the battery level on each one. And have it notify when the battery level updates.

```
public func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didDiscoverServices error: Error?) {

    for service in peripheral.services! {
        if service.uuid == DeviceService.BatteryUUID { // 180F is common to all devices
        let theCharacteristic = [DeviceCharacteristics.AllBatteryUUID] // 2A19 common
            peripheral.discoverCharacteristics(theCharacteristic, for: service)
        }
    }
}
public func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didDiscoverCharacteristicsFor service: CBService, error: Error?) {

    for characteristic in service.characteristics! {

        if characteristic.uuid == DeviceCharacteristics.AllBatteryUUID {
            self.activePeripheral?.setNotifyValue(true, for: characteristic)

            peripheral.readValue(for: characteristic)
        }
}

 public func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didUpdateValueFor characteristic: CBCharacteristic, error: Error?) {

    // for battery level
    if characteristic.uuid == DeviceCharacteristics.AllBatteryUUID {
        self.delegate?.bLEManagerDidReceiveData(data: characteristic.value, char: characteristic)
    }
}
```

The problem is there is no way to distinguish between different peripherals battery levels. How should this be done?

Comment: Have you tried using the peripheral's identifier?

Comment: @Michael - how to you read a characteristic with only the peripheral Identifier?

Comment: In `didUpdateValueFor` callback u get peripheral and characteristic. The `characteristic.uuid` is the same, but `peripheral.identifier` should be different for each peripheral